# How to configure an Ethernet port on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, ip

I have one (physical) Ethernet port on my laptop which is running Ubuntu OS. My goal is to configure the Ethernet port to use an IP address falling within 192.168.0.3 to 192.168.0.254.

What is the correct and easiest way on Ubuntu to assign the Ethernet port an IP address?

Comment: Are you using desktop? (I'd use network-manager on desktop) or a server? (ie. command without network-manager).

Comment: Why not use the standard DHCP method?